# how to launch different view controllers for different local notifications in ios 10

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, appdelegate, nsnotification

I am receiving multiple local notifications in my app at different times. I want to launch different view controllers for my app depending on the local notification received. I know about the launch options in didfinishlaunching and didreceive notifications But I dont know how to detect which notification is received and take action according to the notification received.Even when I  managed to do that, the problem is that I am able to open a view controller from the app delegate but it is no longer attached to the navigation controller that it is otherwise attached to the storyboard. How to do that? Heres my code:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {


       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let customViewController:WebViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "webVC") as! WebViewController

        let index=Constants.instructionsData.count - 1
        customViewController.url=Constants.instructionsData[index].weblink!
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = customViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use notification in iOS 10, so I understand you want to use UNNotification. When you use UNNotificationRequest there is argument called identifier. You can use it to distinguish, which notification send this request. If you use the "old" notifications, you just give selector which will be executed when notification is received.

Edited:
In your code you are changing root view controller, so how do you want the navigation controller to last? You are not using segues.
try:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let customViewController:WebViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "webVC") as! WebViewController
self.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(customViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: what is the method to get the identifier from the notification in didreceive notification

Comment: try response.notification.request.identifier

Comment: Mate, I managed to do that and the problem is that I am able to open a view controller from the app delegate but it is no longer attached to the navigation controller that it is otherwise attached to the storyboard. How to do that?